# ajax POST call to controller gives null value in spring

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I am sending a AJAX post request to my controller. The call goes through,however, the value sent as parameter is null.

AJAX JQUERY CALL:

```
var inValueURL = "/list/invalue";
var filter_data = {
        supplierid: 1
    };


    $filterSupplierName.on('change',function(){
         console.log("before ajax request");
            $.ajax({
                url: inValueUrl, 
                type: 'POST',
                data:JSON.stringify(filter_data),
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (response) {
                    $("table").html(response);
                },
                error: function () {
                    //your error code
                }
            });
        });
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "invalue", method = RequestMethod.POST,headers = "Accept=application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String redire(@RequestBody Value<Integer> supplierid ){
        System.out.println(supplierid.getValue()); // this is null
        return "success1";
    }
```

Value class:

```
public class Value<T> {

    public Value() {}

    public Value(T t) {
        this.value = t;
    }

    private T value;

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Why does the supplierid remain null. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your `Value` class look like?  Is `supplierId` an attribute of `Value`?  If so, you probably don't need to 'stringify' the request data.

Comment: edited to include the value class. No supplier id is not an attribute of the class.

Comment: Is there any reason that you need to use `Value` as the controller method argument, as opposed to just using an `Integer` or `String`?

Comment: Nope. I just created that so  I can use it at many places . However just using string or integer throws 400 bad request error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that your controller method argument, `Value<Integer>` is not null, but `value.getValue()` is null, is that Spring tries to map request parameters to domain objects by name.  You are passing `{supplierid=1}` as your data, but your target object, `value`, has no `setSupplierid` method, so the object is instantiated, but no values are set.

There are a couple solutions to your problem, depending on your needs.

**1. Use @RequestParam**

It would seem the easiest solution here would be to change your method signature to always expect an integer named `supplierid`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "invalue", method = RequestMethod.POST,headers = "Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public String redire(@RequestParam Integer supplierid ){
    System.out.println(supplierid); // this is no longer null
    return "success1";
}
```

**2. Use a `Map`**

If your controller does not always know what type of data it will receive, you can just toss all of your input into a `Map` and handle the input parameters appropriately:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "invalue", method = RequestMethod.POST,headers = "Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public String redire(@RequestBody Map<String,String> data ){
    if (data.containsKey("supplierid")){
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(data.get("supplierid"))); // this is no longer null
    }
    return "success1";
}
```

Though this is not strictly necessary, since the `HttpServletRequest` object present in your controller methods already contains a map of all input parameters:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "invalue", method = RequestMethod.POST,headers = "Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public String redire(HttpServletRequest request){
    if (request.getParameterMap.containsKey("supplierid")){
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameterMap.get("supplierid")[0])); // this is no longer null
    }
    return "success1";
}
```

**3. Use a custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`**

If you absolutely have to use your `Value` class, you can look into extending the `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` class, which is responsible for mapping HTTP request parameters to Java objects.  There are several questions on Stack Overflow that already tackle this subject.

Comment: HI, thanks for the answer. when i try method 1 and method 2 . I get  "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" Error .

Comment: Try removing the `headers` argument from the `@RequestMapping` annotation, and replacing `contentType: "application/json"` in the jQuery AJAX method with `dataType: "json"`.

Comment: Oops . No it s working fine. I had a typo. The method 2 works. But if (request.getParameterMap().containsKey("supplierid")){} is not executed at all. Still getting null values . IS there a different way to send data?

Comment: I tried printing request.getParameter("supplierid") and it shows null.